# Changing Default text of a Plain Text Content Control of a existing .docx file

Tags: java, ms-office, docx4j

I am given a .docx template for which I need to populate in my java application. Initially, I am planning to use Apache POI, since before this, I was tasked to fill up a .xlsx template and it worked well. But, based on my research, doc4j is more suitable for my case.

My case is that this .docx template uses Plain Text Content Control like this:

[image]

Now, upon inspection to its XML structure, I see the `<w:sdt>` directly under `<w:p>` directly under the `<w:body>` tag.

```
<w:body>
    ...
    <w:p w:rsidR="00ED05E8" w:rsidRPr="00DA4BE7" w:rsidRDefault="00AC5B37" w:rsidP="00BA6F7F">
        ...
        <w:sdt>
            <w:sdtPr>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                    <w:i/>
                    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                    <w:u w:val="single"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:alias w:val="Name of Office/Agency Name"/>
                <w:tag w:val="Name of Office/Agency Name"/>
                <w:id w:val="-781645881"/>
                <w:placeholder>
                    <w:docPart w:val="DefaultPlaceholder_-1854013440"/>
                </w:placeholder>
                <w:text/>
            </w:sdtPr>
            <w:sdtEndPr/>
            <w:sdtContent>
                <w:r w:rsidR="00340180" w:rsidRPr="00616BA5">
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                        <w:i/>
                        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                        <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        <w:u w:val="single"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>(Name of Office/Agency Name)</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:sdtContent>
        </w:sdt>
        ...
</w:body>
```

I want to change the text on that `<w:t>` of that `<w:sdt>` from "(Name of Agency)" into a different String. The problem is that I do not know how and is stucked on after these lines:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage document = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(...));
MainDocumentPart mainDocument = document.getMainDocumentPart();
```

I have this `w:id` of `-781645881`, but I don't know what to do with this information. Is this even the `itemId` referred on this [`ContentControlsXmlEdit` sample class from the docx4j site](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlsXmlEdit.java)?

I cannot fetch that `<w:sdt>` node even after using the following code:

```
String itemId = "-781645881".toLowerCase();
CustomXmlDataStoragePart customXmlDataStoragePart = (CustomXmlDataStoragePart)wordMLPackage.getCustomXmlDataStorageParts().get(itemId);
CustomXmlDataStorage customXmlDataStorage = customXmlDataStoragePart.getData();
```

What should I do to be able to change the value of the plain text content control?

Comment: That content control is not bound to a Custom XML part.  The w:id is just a unique identifier, not really useful.

Comment: You'll want a databinding element; the walkthrough document at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/sample-docs/word/databinding might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is something I devised out of desperation for the following reasons:

1. I quite not mastered yet accessing things in the Word's `.xml` programmatically using [docx4j](/questions/tagged/docx4j).
2. I extracted the exact `.xml` file of the `.docx` file I'm processing.
3. There are no `storeItemid` found on my `.xml` of the `.docx` file.

Here is my utility class written in `.groovy`:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart
import org.docx4j.wml.CTBookmark
import org.docx4j.wml.P
import org.docx4j.wml.R
import org.docx4j.wml.SdtBlock
import org.docx4j.wml.SdtContent
import org.docx4j.wml.SdtRun
import org.docx4j.wml.Text

class WordReport {
    private WordprocessingMLPackage document
    private Map<String, String> contentControlMapping
    private Map<String, Object> reportArgs

    public WordReport(Map<String, Object> reportArgs) {
        document = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage()
        this.reportArgs = reportArgs
    }

    public WordprocessingMLPackage exportReport() {
        return document
    }

    private String getNewMapping(String contentControlText)  {
        return contentControlMapping.get(contentControlText)
    }

    private boolean isMapped(String contentControlText) {
        return contentControlMapping.containsKey(contentControlText)
    }

    protected void mapNewMapping() {
        MainDocumentPart mainDocument = document.getMainDocumentPart()
        List<Object> nodes = mainDocument.getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w:sdt", false)

        String key
        SdtContent content
        nodes.each { n ->
            if(n instanceof SdtBlock) {
                content = n.getSdtContent()
            }
            else if(n instanceof JAXBElement) {
                if(n.getValue() instanceof SdtRun) {
                    content = n.getValue().getSdtContent()
                }
            }

            content.getContent().each { sdtcc ->
                if(sdtcc instanceof P) {
                    sdtcc.getContent().each { pc ->
                        pc.getContent().each { rc ->
                            println "rc.getValue().getClass(): " + rc.getValue().getClass()
                            if(rc.getValue() instanceof Text) {
                                key = rc.getValue().getValue()
                                isMapped(key) ? rc.getValue().setValue(getNewMapping(key)) : null
                            }
                            else if(rc.getValue() instanceof R) {
                                rc.getValue().getContent().each { rrc ->
                                    if(rrc instanceof JAXBElement) {
                                        key = rrc.getValue().getValue()
                                        isMapped(key) ? rrc.getValue().setValue(getNewMapping(key)) : null
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(sdtcc instanceof R) {
                    sdtcc.getContent().each { rc ->
                        if(rc instanceof JAXBElement) {
                            key = rc.getValue().getValue()
                            isMapped(key) ? rc.getValue().setValue(getNewMapping(key)) : null
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(sdtcc instanceof JAXBElement) {
                    if(sdtcc.getValue() instanceof CTBookmark) {

                    }
                    else if(sdtcc.getValue() instanceof JAXBElement) {
                        key = sdtcc.getValue().getValue()
                        isMapped(key) ? sdtcc.getValue().setValue(getNewMapping(key)) : null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setMapping(Map contentControlMapping) {
        this.contentControlMapping = contentControlMapping
    }
}
```

The core part of this class is the `mapNewMapping()` method. What basically it does is it maps the mapping on the `contentControlMapping` variable into any `<w:t>` inside `<w:sdt>`s, regardless whether it is directly under a `<w:sdt>` or if it's inside of `<w:rPr>`, etc. I retrieve the list of all `<w:sdt>` using the `getJAXBNodesViaXPath()` method.

The limitation of this is this can only support limited set of combinations  of `P`, `R`, `CTBookmark`, `SdtBlock`, `SdtContent`, `SdtRun`. If the `<w:t>` is found inside complex or deep nested `.xml` that I have not anticipated, it will not be mapped. That is why I included mentioning that I have read first the `.xml` of the `.docx` file.